# PN532 HSU Intermediate Reads on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port, nfc

I can not reliably get the [PN532](https://www.adafruit.com/product/364) to respond to commands, other than the firmware info command. I am using HSU on Windows with a FTDI cable obtained from Adafruit as well as the v1.6 of their dev board.

The black reads are from the `ReadFile` call timing out, it is set to 20 with all the flow control stuff disabled.

I do not think it is the cable, as the wake up and firmware version stuff is valid and works every single time.

Serial port opening code:

```
// Open the COM port
HANDLE commHandle = CreateFile(
    "\\\\.\\COM5",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    null,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    null
);

// Get the existing settings
DCB serialSettings;
GetCommState(
    commHandle,
    &serialSettings
);
// Page 26 of the User Manual specifies these settings
serialSettings.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
serialSettings.ByteSize = 8;
serialSettings.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
serialSettings.Parity = NOPARITY;

// These did not make it any better or worse
serialSettings.fParity = false;
serialSettings.fOutxCtsFlow = false;
serialSettings.fOutxDsrFlow = false;
serialSettings.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
serialSettings.fDsrSensitivity = false;
serialSettings.fTXContinueOnXoff = true;
serialSettings.fOutX = false;
serialSettings.fInX = false;
serialSettings.fErrorChar = false;
serialSettings.fNull = false;
serialSettings.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
serialSettings.fAbortOnError = false;

// Setup the state
SetCommState(
    commHandle,
    &serialSettings
);

// Clean out any buffers or flags
PurgeComm(
    commHandle,
    PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR
);
```

Data that is written to and read from the `HANDLE`, using the sizes that where obtained from the output param.

```
Write:  55 55 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 02 FE D4 02 2A 00
Read:  00 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 00 FF 06 FA D5 03 32 01 06 07 E8 00
Write:  00 00 FF 00 FF 00
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Write:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 14 01 14 01 02 00
Read: 
Read:
```

Edit:
This appears to only happen on Windows, I tried the same process on Debian and it worked fine. I am using Java for this so I just had to rewrite the natives, so the communications itself seem functional. This is quite strange to me.

Comment: It seems like it might be because it was waiting for a tag to come into range, so I might need to do some timeout stuff. After more testing I will post an answer if this is the case.

Comment: It would appear as thought that is sometimes the case, at least on Windows. It was working and now it is not, with and without a tag on it. This is quite odd to me.